# How do I create an expectedResponse dictionary based on the actualResponse using Gson?

Tags: java, json, kotlin, intellij-idea, gson

I am trying to make a dictionary that has the headers stored in ClassResponse and follows the format of responseBody. I keep getting this error message:

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY
```

When I run this code:

```
val goalResponses: ClassResponse = Gson().fromJson(responseBody)
```

And I get this error message:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT
```

When I run this code:

```
val goalResponses: List<ClassResponse> = Gson().fromJson(responseBody)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the objects inside the class as the wrong type. If you fix the objects in the class and make them the correct type, then you should no longer see this error.

My solution was:

```
data class ClassResponse(
    val id : String,
    val names : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
)
val goalResponses: ClassResponse = Gson().fromJson(responseBody)
```